# Vidick's proof of parallel DI-QKD

Tags: quantum-computing, quantum-information, cryptography

This question is based on the paper- https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.08508.

As far as I understand, for this proof Vidick uses a quantum parallel repetition for 3 player- Alice, Bob and Eve but the results in the anchored games paper and Lemma 4 of the paper are only for 2 players. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the proof indeed relies on a 3 player parallel repetition result for anchored games. A proof sketch for multiplayer anchored games has been given in Sec 5.3 of the [anchored games paper v1](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3055399.3055433).

There seems to be typo in Lemma 4 of the parallel DIQKD [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.08508)-- it should have been $\tau_{\eta, t}^\ast (G_\eta) \leq e^{-\Omega(\delta^9 n)}$ in the lemma.